# Unexplained memory error using C++, SDL, OpenGL and GLEW

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, sdl, glew

This is my entire application (stripped down to the essentials):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window* gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    SDL_GLContext gContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext( gWindow );
    glewInit();

    GLfloat *floatArray = new GLfloat(108);
    floatArray[107] = 0.0f;

    GLuint glBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &glBuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

This and the required libraries are all compiled in Visual Studio 2012.

This code initialises all the required systems for an OpenGL context, in the right order and nothing is missing as far as I can see (cleaning up is only needed after the point it breaks so I took that out).

It breaks on the line `glGenBuffers(1, &glBuffer);`, with the error "SOFT323_vs11_2012.exe has triggered a breakpoint."

Setting an element beyond `floatArray[9]` is required to break it.

How do I approach this problem? Is it a glitch with one of the libraries or am I using them incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This allocates a single `GLfloat`, initialized with the value `108.0f`.

```
GLfloat *floatArray = new GLfloat(108);
```

You wanted to allocate an **array**:

```
GLfloat *floatArray = new GLfloat[108];
```

Comment: And make sure to use `delete[]` (not `delete`!) to free your array.

Comment: Or just use `std::vector<>` and (mostly) not care :)